Can a suicide note be a valid will?
Hypothetically, if someone leaves instructions in a note for dividing up their savings and/or assets (i.e. a will), and subsequently commits suicide with the note on their person, would this note be considered a legally binding will in the absence of an actual will? Mainly wondering for the UK but other jurisdictions welcome.

Apart from being an unwitnessed Will, it would have to be established that it was not murder made to look like suicide, with a fake Will planted on the victim. Related: Are holographic wills really routinely thrown out by probate courts?

australia
Depends
While each state has formal requirements for a valid will, the law also provides for judicial discretion. This has included unsent text messages.
If the document or verbal statement clear shows testamentary intent, it will be treated as a will or as a codicil to an existing will.

The text message thing is really interesting, especially for one that hadn't even been sent.

switzerland
Maybe, if the formal requirements are met. A will has very strong formal requirements to be binding; it must either have been signed in front of a notary and/or at least two witnesses or it must have been fully written by hand. In this case, if the (later) deceased has written the note by hand, dated it properly and signed it, it will probably be considered valid.

Is there no "sound mind" requirement in Switzerland?

@user71659 There is (Art 519 ZGB), but I can't say whether "intending to commit suicide" is enough to disqualify that. There was recently a story about someone who committed assisted suicide (which is legal in Switzerland) but gave a page-long interview the day before.

@user71659 "of sound mind" does not mean "does not do things that I disagree with". It means "he knows that he is writing a document that will be used to assign his possessions after his death, and he knows which possessions he has, and he is finding them to actual, existing persons."

@PMF For assisted suicide, my understanding is you necessarily must be declared of sound mind during that process, and medical evaluation and documentation is needed. So there's certainly evidence in the assisted case, which is a subset of OP's question. However, if you're going through the assisted suicide process, you probably would do your will the formal way.

@SJuan76 So you're going to claim that the testator was all of that, without any witnesses and immediately after did something very bad to themselves? For somebody who didn't commit suicide, you could have witnesses and evidence that they were competent in the period after signing: they went to work, they talked to their doctor and relatives. At minimum, the suicide doesn't help the case that they were competent.

@user71659 The judge will have to decide that, based on the circumstances of the suicide and the contents of said will. It will be different when the will contains just a few donations to charities VS skipping his son.

It's conceivable to commit suicide and be of sound mind, for example if you know that suicide is the only thing that will stop an extremely painful death from cancer within one month. An objective decision that breaking a law is better for you than not breaking it doesn't mean you are not of sound mind.

france
Yes, provided the conditions listed at article 970 of the civil code are respected:

Le testament olographe ne sera point valable s'il n'est écrit en entier, daté et signé de la main du testateur : il n'est assujetti à aucune autre forme.


A holographic will is not valid unless entirely written [by hand], dated and signed from the hand of the decedent. It is subject to no other condition of form.

In addition, there are conditions of content (in particular one cannot entirely disinherit one’s children). Those apply to notarized wills as well (though, of course, notarized wills will have been read by a legal professional who can alert to deficiencies in that regard).

united-states
The general rule in a majority of U.S. jurisdictions (about 27 states) is that a document can function as  a will without being witnessed if the material provisions of the will are in the handwriting of the person allegedly making a will and if the language of the writing indicates an intent to direct the disposition on that person's property after their death. A document of this type is called a "holographic will". Two more U.S. states recognize holographic wills made in exigent circumstances, and seven more states beyond these twenty-nine recognize holographic wills that were valid where they were made. At least ten U.S. states do not recognize holographic wills under any circumstances.
Not every U.S. jurisdiction allows holographic wills, and in the other direction, a few U.S. states allow a court to dispense with the handwriting requirement if there is a clear intent to make a disposition of property effective at death. A state by state breakdown is available here.
The fact that someone is suicidal or contemplating suicide at the time will not usually invalidate a will. There are basically three things that, if not present, can invalidate a will which has the requisite formalities (such as being in the handwriting of the person making it):

The person must have testamentary capacity, which means that they know who the "natural objections of their bounty" (i.e. family, friends, loved ones, charities that they have favored) are, that they have a general idea of what they own, and that they understand what their will purports to do with their property at their death, and

If the person making the will is suffering from hallucinations, the hallucinations may not influence the dispositions of property made in the will, and

The person must not be subject to undue influence from someone else (i.e. their will-power must not be overcome by someone else causing them to change their dispositions of property made in the will).


While it is conceivable that one of these three conditions might not be met in some particular case by a suicidal individual, in general, none of these three requirements is inconsistent with being suicidal.
united-kingdom
In contrast, in Scotland, England, Wales, and Northern Ireland, unwitnessed holographic wills written after 1 August 1995 are invalid. So, in those jurisdictions, the unwitnessed suicide note would not constitute a valid will. Prior to that date, holographic wills written in Scotland were valid in the United Kingdom.

You should add the UK portion to its own answer as it it's easily missed, and I'd be happy to accept it.
